# XPath Check if ID exists within drop down. Class check

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, class, xpath

thanks in advance. Noobie to Python here and I am trying to automate value entries into a website via Selenium and the respective XPath values.

How it is supposed to function is that I send keys of the dynamic 'ID' into the input box and the ID will pop up and I select the ID. This works. Right now I am running into the issue where the ID does not exist and the tool ends up stalling out. I know I need an `If` function, then execute an `elif` if it does not exist but I am lost when it comes to these kind of statements with XPaths and need a little bit of guidance.

I have the class XPath of the pop up value stating the ID does not exist:

```
<li class="vv_list_no_items vv_item_indent listNoItems">No results match "1234567890123456"</li>
```

The confusing part is also having dynamic IDs where "1234567890123456" can be any ID.

Current code is below, sorry for the indenting as this was grabbed out of a larger set of scripts.

```
                try:
                   wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 10)
                   # Inputs Legal Entity
                   elem = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,
                                                                 "//*[@id='di3Form']/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/input"))).send_keys(
                       LE)
                   elem = wait.until(
                       EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='veevaBasePage']/ul[3]/li/a"))).click()

                   LE = None

                   # Inputs WWID

                   elem = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,
                                                                 "//*[@id='di3Form']/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[4]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/input"))).send_keys(ID)
                   
                   elem = wait.until(
                       EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='veevaBasePage']/ul[4]/li[2]/a/em"))).click()

                   # Inputs Country
                   elem = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,
                                                                 "//*[@id='di3Form']/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[5]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/input"))).send_keys(
                       Country)
                   elem = wait.until(
                       EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='veevaBasePage']/ul[5]/li/a"))).click()

                   # Save
                   elem = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,
                                                                 "//a[@class='docInfoSaveButton save vv_button vv_primary']/span[@class='vv_button_text vv_ellipsis' and text()='Save']")))
                   browser.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", elem)


                   wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 15)

                   # Click dropdown menu arrow
                   elem = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(
                       (By.XPATH, "//*[@id='di3Header']/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div/button")))
                   browser.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", elem)

                   wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 100)

                   # Click "Publish"
                   elem = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,
                                                                 "/html/body/div[6]/div/ul/li")))
                   browser.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", elem)

                   #Confirm Publish
                   elem = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,
                                                                 "//a[@class='save vv_button vv_primary']/span[@class='vv_button_text' and text()='Yes']")))
                   browser.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", elem)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `xpath` contains, with `find_elements` that `returns` a `list` and have a if `condition` that if it `is >0`, then `No match found` string would be present in `UI`.

```
try :
    no_match = "No results match" + " " + '"' + WWID + '"'

    if (len(driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//li[contains(text(),'{}')]".format(no_match)))) > 0:
        print("Code has found No results match, String ")
        # do what ever you wanna do here. 
    else:
        print("There is not locator that contains, No results match")
except:
    print("Something went wrong")
    pass
```